# how to inner join two tables which are in 2 different mysql database on same server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, inner-join

How to inner join two tables which are in 2 different mysql database using php mysql_query

The name of databases are "database" and "image_database" and the table are "user" and "user_image"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 $query =" select * from database.user d
          inner join image_databse.user_image i
          on d.<column_name>=i.<column_name>";
mysql_query($query);
```

Although mysql_select_db() selects one database , if you have required permission to access the databases from which data has to be pulled , only one mysql_select_db() function to select either of database is required as other database will be referenced automatically. 

Also make sure the user specified in mysql_connect() has the privileges to connect to both the databases. 
Note : mysql_ functions are being deprecated , use mysqli extensions instead to avoid problems later eg mysqli_select_db()